# *ngIf does not toggle back to false in else block

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I am using Angular7, npm 6.4.1, node 10.15.3.

I am just playing around with ngIf, this does nothing useful. I am using two buttons to toggle back and forth between displaying and hiding a header. While it was just an `ngIf` statement, it was working fine with the following code:

```
    <p>Do you want to see the last header?</p>
    <button (click)="yesHeader()">Yes please!</button>
    <button (click)="noHeader()">PLEASE G-D NO!</button>

    <h2 *ngIf="displayHeader" style="color:blue">Here it is in all its glory!</h2>
```

and

```
public displayHeader=false;

  yesHeader(){
    this.displayHeader=true
  }

  noHeader(){
    this.displayHeader=false
  }
```

And that worked fine, showing the header when clicking the `yesHeader` button and hiding it again when clicking the `noHeader` button.

However, when I added an ngIf Else block, it stopped toggling back and forth. The change was to the following:

```
    <p>Do you want to see the last header?</p>
    <button (click)="yesHeader()">Yes please!</button><button (click)="noHeader()">NO! NO!</button>

    <h2 *ngIf="displayHeader; else noHeader" style="color:blue">Here it is in all its glory!</h2>

    <ng-template #noHeader>
      <h5>You don't know what you're missing!</h5>
    </ng-template>
```

Now, it displays `You don't know what you're missing!` at start, and switches to the header if I click yes. But it doesn't toggle back to hiding the header if I click the no button after that.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get it to toggle back?

As an added datapoint, if I leave the else block, but take `else noHeader` out of the ngIf statement, it still doesn't toggle back. So seemingly the existence of the ng-template is what is stopping things up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that there is a name conflict of `noHeader`. It being used in your example as both a method on the component class as well as the name of the `ng-template`. Try changing either the name of the method or name of the template:

```
<p>Do you want to see the last header?</p>
<button (click)="yesHeader()">Yes please!</button><button (click)="noHeader()">NO! NO!</button>

<h2 *ngIf="displayHeader; else noHeaderTemplate" style="color:blue">Here it is in all its glory!</h2>

<ng-template #noHeaderTemplate>
  <h5>You don't know what you're missing!</h5>
</ng-template>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tr5aeq) in action.

Comment: Can't give a check until my q is old enough.

Answer (score 2):

Your template is called the same as function: `noHeader`.

You have name collision problem, you can't call `noHeader` function, Angular thinks you're referencing `noHeader` template reference.

```
<ng-template #noHeaderTemplate>
  <h5>You don't know what you're missing!</h5>
</ng-template>
```

Or

```
hideHeader() {
  this.displayHeader = false;
}
```

A proper IDE should tell you "Member noHeader is not callable".